# Bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04 Dell

Tags: bluetooth, dell

Dell Inspiron-3542 inbuilt bluetooth is not working.

Working properly on previously installed Windows.

Some command reference:

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
$ bluetooth
bluetooth = none (no device)

$ sudo rfkill list
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ uname -r
4.10.0-28-generic
```

Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)